# Start activity according to button hold time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm developing an application where there are several buttons in the UI and when the user clicks a  button, first an audio output is heard, and if the user keeps on holding the button another activity is launched according to the button the user is holding. I've got as far as the audio output but am at a loss on how to implement the button hold action. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.call);
    button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // Start a new Activity     
            return false;
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

         // Play the Audio
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

There is [on click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) and there is [on long click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html), both can be registered on a button. Maybe play audio on click and start activity on long click.